# Parse Syntax Woo Commerce Plugin Issue

Tags: syntax, wordpress, syntax-error, woocommerce

I hope someone can please help. I am very new to this coding world, and I was trying to edit a website template which I bought. I am receiving the following note '
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*' in /home/thebrooc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/admin/woocommerce-admin-hooks.php on line 72' AND i now can no longer do anything at all to the website. I cant even put the holding page back up or anything. Please can someone advise me what I should do? Thank you

I have pasted the code below (it is for the woocommerce plugin)

```
<?php
/**
 * WooCommerce Admin Hooks
 *
 * Action/filter hooks used for WooCommerce functions.
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @category    Admin
 * @package     WooCommerce/Admin
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

/**
 * Events
 *
 * @see woocommerce_delete_post()
 * @see woocommerce_trash_post()
 * @see woocommerce_untrash_post()
 * @see woocommerce_preview_emails()
 * @see woocommerce_prevent_admin_access()
 * @see woocommerce_check_download_folder_protection()
 * @see woocommerce_ms_protect_download_rewite_rules()
 */
add_action('delete_post', 'woocommerce_delete_post');
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'woocommerce_trash_post');
add_action('untrash_post', 'woocommerce_untrash_post');
add_action('admin_init', 'woocommerce_preview_emails');
add_action('admin_init', 'woocommerce_prevent_admin_access');
add_action('woocommerce_settings_saved', 'woocommerce_check_download_folder_protection');
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'woocommerce_ms_protect_download_rewite_rules');

/**
 * File uploads
 *
 * @see woocommerce_downloads_upload_dir()
 * @see woocommerce_media_upload_downloadable_product()
 */
add_filter('upload_dir', 'woocommerce_downloads_upload_dir');
add_action('media_upload_downloadable_product',  'woocommerce_media_upload_downloadable_product');

/**
 * Shortcode buttons
 *
 * @see woocommerce_add_shortcode_button()
 * @see woocommerce_refresh_mce()
 */
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_add_shortcode_button' );
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_version', 'woocommerce_refresh_mce' );

/**
 * Category/term ordering
 *
 * @see woocommerce_create_term()
 * @see woocommerce_delete_term()
 */
add_action( "create_term", 'woocommerce_create_term', 5, 3 );
add_action( "delete_term", 'woocommerce_delete_term', 5 );

/**
 * Bulk editing
 *
 * @see woocommerce_bulk_admin_footer()
 * @see woocommerce_order_bulk_action()
 * @see woocommerce_order_bulk_admin_notices()
 */
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'woocommerce_bulk_admin_footer', 10 );
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'woocommerce_order_bulk_action' );
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'woocommerce_order_bulk_admin_notices' );

/**
 * Mijireh Gateway
 */
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( 'WC_Gateway_Mijireh', 'add_page_slurp_meta' ) );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_page_slurp', array( 'WC_Gateway_Mijireh', 'page_slurp' ) );
```

Comment: are you sure you pasted the right file? because there is no error on line 72. for those who don't know, line 72 is the /** line directly above Mijireh Gateway. if it is the right file, then try deleting lines 72-74, and see if that fixes it. this is not a permanent solution, but it may give more insight to the actual problem.

Comment: See if you can change the template(theme) to something else, like twentytwelve. If that makes the error goes away, then it probably has nothing to do with woocommerce. Make sure your woocommerce version is compatible with the theme. If you made changes to the theme, upload the original theme before you changed it, see if that works with woocommerce.